# Relative Frequency in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

Not sure if my subject is correct.

I have a dataset like this

```
Category          Family        Item          Week
A                  A1            A11            1
A                  A2            A12            1
B                  B1            B11            1
C                  C2            C12            1
A                  A1            A11            2
A                  A2            A12            2
B                  B1            B11            3
C                  C2            C12            3
C                  C1            C11            3
A                  A2            A12            3
```

and so on..

I want to Know how frequent two different items are appearing in this table.

For example:

```
Week 1 has A11, A12, B11, C12
Week 2 has A11, A12
Week 3 has B11, B12, C11, A12
```

Frequent combinations are

```
A12,A11 which came 2 times out of 3 weeks
B11, A12 which came 2 times out of 3 weeks
```

Like that

Any function we can get this?

Comment: I guess you should have a look at basket analysis / association rules, for instance in package `arules`. Try next time to populate a sample data set we can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cbind.data.frame()` along with `table()` function, to see different combiantions like below:

```
 > table(cbind.data.frame(df$Week,df$Item))
              df$Item
 df$Week A11 A12 B11 C11 C12
       1   1   1   1   0   1
       2   1   1   0   0   0
       3   0   1   1   1   1

 > table(cbind.data.frame(df$Item,df$Week))
          df$Week
 df$Item 1 2 3
     A11 1 1 0
     A12 1 1 1
     B11 1 0 1
     C11 0 0 1
     C12 1 0 1

 > table(cbind.data.frame(df$Family,df$Week))
          df$Week
 df$Family 1 2 3
        A1 1 1 0
        A2 1 1 1
        B1 1 0 1
        C1 0 0 1
        C2 1 0 1

 > table(cbind.data.frame(df$Family,df$Item))
                 df$Item
 df$Family A11 A12 B11 C11 C12
        A1   2   0   0   0   0
        A2   0   3   0   0   0
        B1   0   0   2   0   0
        C1   0   0   0   1   0
        C2   0   0   0   0   2

 > table(cbind.data.frame(df$Category,df$Item))
                    df$Item
  df$Category A11 A12 B11 C11 C12
            A   2   3   0   0   0
            B   0   0   2   0   0
            C   0   0   0   1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a so brilliant solution (to be honest it is the uncomfortable format I can imagine to work with), but just for fun I've tried a solution that match your desired output:

```
 p <- data.frame(a = setNames(tapply(df$Item, df$Week, paste), paste("Week", unique(df$Week), "has:") ))
 p
                             a
Week 1 has: A11, A12, B11, C12
Week 2 has:           A11, A12
Week 3 has: B11, C12, C11, A12
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want some simple array you can easily call and tweak later, the first thing can be neatly accomplished by

```
itemperweek=list()
for (i in 1:3){
itemperweek[[i]]=df$item[df$week==i]
}
```

the second you can also do with

```
tableperweek13=table (df$Item[df$Week%in%c(1:3)])
tableperweek13[tableperweek13>1]
```

If have way more levels in the table than 1 and 2, I suggest using the quantile()-function instead of 1 in the second line